# Redux typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment - useDispatch

Tags: typescript, redux, eslint, typescript-eslint

[image]

I am using React, TypeScript, ESlint, and TypeScript-ESlint.  There are no issues with this.

When I installed Redux, React-Redux, and @types/react-redux, the Redux types are being ignored by TypeScript-ESlint.  I also installed and uninstalled @types/redux.

Everything in the Redux API like useDispatch(), useSelector(), combineReducers() throws linting errors for "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value."

From the Redux Docs, useDispatch() should work without any special typing.
[image]

**How can I configure TypeScript-ESlint to work with Redux?**

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to import it.

Comment: Or you can try reloading your IDE (looks like VSCode, either by restarting it or "Reload" in the command palette), sometimes the ts language server is a bit slow in picking up changes.

Comment: @Janik you are absolutely right, I didn't have any problems with earlier libraries before installing Redux so I didn't think it would be the editor.  I did a hard quit and when I reopened the editor all of the typescript-eslint errors disappeared and I verified by building.  Post as an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Great to hear it helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, the typescript language server within vs code has a hard time picking up changes to the types. Try to "Reload" it using the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P and searching for "restart") or completely restarting vs code.